# CKEDITOR Image Properties Browse Button

Tags: image, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have found a neat plugin for [CKEDITOR](http://ckeditor.com/) called *[bgimage](https://github.com/smoqadam/background-image-ckeditor-plugin)* that allows a user to select a section of text and wrap said text within `div` and apply the `background image` style attribute ([Background Image plugin should use Selected Text.](https://github.com/smoqadam/background-image-ckeditor-plugin/pull/5/commits/6b3cbcd1f37998bd1e076f342a996079c587af9e)).

I was wondering how can I replace the **Image URL** with **Image Browse** button as found within *Image Properties*?

[image: Image Properties]

[image: BG Image Plugin]

Do I need to add an additional button to the vbox then make the necessary connections between FileBrowser and the associated Button? (I can't seem to find the relevant Developer Docs, regarding this problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete documentation for adding the file browser to your dialog is actually available here: [Adding File Manager to a Dialog Window](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_dialog_add_file_browser).